# Is there an API to access location history on a mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, location

I can't seem to find any public API for a third party app to (once authorized) access a mobile user's location history (e.g. what is shown in https://www.google.com/maps/timeline). I know I can track a user's current location and receive updates, but it would be nice to not have to double up on something that a user's mobile device is likely already doing.

Is it true that such an API does not exist whether it is for Android or iOS? If not, are there any plans to?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, the Core Location [visits api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_visits_location_service) may provide what you are looking for.

You will only be able to access locations the user has visited after you have obtained permission.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if it's able to get any previously saved location data, but at least it can track a user's location, even if the app is not opened.